# REST API to get Amazon reviews?

Tags: java, rest

I'm interested to investigate the structure of amazon reviews a little further and wondered if there is a REST API Endpoint to get the reviews for some products back (academic background/ linguistic research).
Since I'm not selling stuff on amazon and want to get reviews fo a variety of products I can't use endpoints which are ment to be used by the sellers themself.

If found an old quest about [some related stuff](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8700875/amazon-product-advertising-api-get-review-rank), but maybe there are some new information I missed.

Thanks in advance